# when I use python multiprocessing, why the processes are in GPU?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, gpu, nvidia

I found that when I use multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async, the processes are actually in GPU, which is very strange.

```
sudo python myfunc.py 1 2>&1 | tee myfunc.log
```

I use 'sudo' because I need the permission to write. The code is some kind like

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=10)
for i in xrange(10):
    pool.apply_async(somefunc, args=myars, kwds=mykwds)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

The following information comes from 'nvidia-smi'

[image: GPU PID TYPE PROCESS NAME (GPU MEMORY USUAGE)]

Comment: is your `somefunc` using [PyCuda](https://mathema.tician.de/software/pycuda/) or calling CUDA kernels?

Comment: no. I have checked my code.@ImanolLuengo